# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 18: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8

I was trying to read a basic txt file in Python by:

```
apple= '/Users....'
with open(apple) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

and the following came up:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 18: invalid continuation byte

I tried with

```
with open(apple, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

but the error message is still the same. Does anyone have an idea what on earth it means?

Comment: It means the file wasn’t encoded in UTF-8

Comment: Try encoding='ISO-8859-1'

Comment: You can visit the https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and/or [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html).